# Was a one way trip to the moon considered by the crew of Apollo 13?

Tags: the-moon, apollo-13, death

I watched the fantastic movie "[Apollo 13](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112384/)" recently and there was one scene that stood out as it looked like the crew was considering making a one way trip and landing on the moon.

The [script](https://sfy.ru/?script=apollo13) goes like this:

> NEWS ANCHOR (on TV)
>   - The problem now is not there's so much question of
>   adequate oxygen supply but it is the rate of consumption of
>   water which is vitally needed for the cooling operations to
>   maintain the electronic systems and so forth.

...

> FRED HAISE
>   - Gotta tell you, I had an itch to take this baby down
>   though, and do some prospecting. Damn we were close.
>
> JIM LOVELL
>   - Gentlemen, what are your intentions?... I'd like to go
>   home. We got a burn coming up. We're gonna need a
>   contingency if we lose comm with Houston. Freddo, let's...
>   let's get an idea where we stand on the consumables. Jack,
>   get into the Odyssey and bag up all the water you can before
>   it freezes in there... Let's go home.

Faced with little chance of returning to Earth, Fred Haise and Jim Lovell seem to be thinking about giving up on the return and focusing on setting foot on the moon. Was this the case?

Comment: This is actually a good question. If it was, it would probably be found in the book "Lost Moon: The Perilous Voyage of Apollo 13" by Jim Lovell and Jeffrey Kluger (sadly, id not not have a physical or electronic version I could search). Since its not on the Air-to-Ground transmissions, it won't be in any of those transcripts. I would not dismiss it completely, since Apollo 10 was not fully fueled exactly so that landing was impossible and no temptation was given.

Comment: I've read lost moon some time ago @Polygnome, IIRC the conversation did take place but Lovell knew it was wishful thinking. He certainly didn't mention anyone discussing landing seriously. These were people with a very good sense of survival or they wouldn't have made good test pilots.

Comment: "What are your intentions?" whether actually spoken by Lovell or not, is clearly a rhetorical question.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

They weren't actually considering it. It's just one of those wishful thinking moments, or a joke to lighten things up. Furthermore, there isn't anything said along those lines in the [official transcripts](https://www.jsc.nasa.gov/history/mission_trans/AS13_TEC.PDF). The time it would have been said was around 3:05:00.

Also, they really couldn't have done so. They had already used fuel from the descent stage. The amount wasn't huge, but it was a [34 second burn](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4029/Apollo_13a_Summary.htm). They also hadn't orbited, which would have consumed a fair bit more fuel. In all, they would have had to use more fuel then the descent stage had to allow it to land, not even counting the fuel they had expended. At best, they could have landed using the ascent stage, which wouldn't have been very likely, as it wasn't designed to be used in that way. And if they had landed, they would have had absolutely no chance of coming home.

Comment: The whole point of a one-way trip is not to come home so I don't know if the amount of fuel is relevant here.

Comment: @Edlothiad Would they have wanted to fatally crash into the moon or would they have wanted to land and walk around and then die from lack of supplies? Both of the current answers are saying that the former would be their only option. Fuel was needed to not fatally crash or fly off into space.

Comment: @ToddWilcox given I was commenting on this original wording "*They had already used fuel from the decent stage. And if they had landed, they would have had absolutely no chance of coming home.*" I don't see your point. I was basing my comment off the fact that if they had intended for a one way mission, having enough fuel to return was not their main worry.

Comment: @Edlothiad Ah, I think I understand. You're mainly questioning why the last sentence is there? Pearson: I thought about it, but I would have had to find something else to change since adding two s's would not be enough. You'll notice there were enough issues with the other answer to make it easy to fit the edit minimum.

Comment: @ToddWilcox hmm yes, apologies for the mis-understanding. It was purely on "*They would have had no chance of coming home*".

Comment: In addition to all the problems above, the LM wasn't built to take 3 people to the surface, even if they hadn't already used up some descent propellant.  It  would have meant leaving Swigert in the CM to freeze to death.  I doubt that was a serious consideration.

Comment: A landing using the ascent stage was not possible, the landing gear was mounted to the descent stage. Without separation from the descent stage, the ascent stage engine could not be used.

Comment: They hadn't used a significant amount of descent-stage fuel at that point. They did a 30-second burn with the DPS about 5.5 hours after the accident, but it was at 40% power, yielding ~12m/s ∆v. However, the ~700 m/s ∆v required to enter lunar orbit from their flyby trajectory would have done so.

Comment: One would think that if the notion were considered at all seriously, the point would have been to at least arrive on the surface alive, an impossibility given the constraints of the situation. Such a thing would most certainly have been no more than a joke to ease the tension of the moment. I'm sure they all felt a duty to each other to make their best effort to return home alive and as well as can be managed under the circumstances, as actually happened. The crew was not nearly so expendable as the mission.

Comment: As I detailed in some comments in response to Uwe's post, this is not as unreasonable as it might originally seem. Without doing any NASA shenanigans (like the kind that saved Apollo 13) it's totally within the realm of the reasonable.

Comment: Ascent fuel supply could be used without jettisoning descent stage by burning in the RCS thrusters. You get less than half your delta-V out of it that way, but you'll get much back for the DPS engine by not carrying the fuel anymore.

Answer (score 32):

The stack of the SM (service module), CM (command module) and LM (lunar module) was on a free return trajectory to Earth. To get into an orbit around the Moon, the main engine of the SM was needed. But the SM was damaged by the explosion of the oxygen tank and no electric power was available in the SM. Some of the parts (tanks, valves, tubes, electric cables) needed for the main engine operation might been damaged.

So without electrical control, the SM engine could not be used for lunar orbit insertion. If they had used the descent stage engine of the LM for lunar orbit insertion, not enough fuel would have been left for a soft landing on the moon. The ascent stage could not be used for landing without separation of the descent stage with the landing gear mounted to it.

The radar used for landing measuring distance, height and speed of descent was mounted to the descent stage, without that the landing would be impossible.

For sources see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_13).

Comment: Can you add some sources?

Comment: They did seriously consider restarting the SM engine though. From the actual photographs of the SM later, it would have started if the electrical power required to open the valves could be found. The tanks retained pressure and the bell was only scratched. The gimbals were damaged but lock gimbal should have worked.

Comment: On the other hand there was a nonzero chance the SM engine exploded due to piping damage from stuff we could not see.

Comment: I'm not sure it's as unreasonable as you make it out to be: the previous burn would have been <20m/s dV. Lunar insertion is ~700m/s dV. The descent stage was rated for 2.5km/s dV and a lunar landing is optimally 1.7km/s... IE, they were still within the realm of possible not using/scrubbing the ascent stage. If they planned ahead, jettisoning the ascent stage fuel before lunar orbital insertion would give them about 30% more dV, or 3.2km/s... which would give them an orbital insertion and landing with nearly normal dV margins (~800m/s extra) entirely on the descent stage... just a TWR bump.

Comment: @TemporalWolf : I doubt that jettisoning the ascent stage fuel was possible without damaging the descent stage. The propellant was hypergolic, the components spontaneously ignite when they come into contact with each other. I don't think the LM had extra propellant dumping valves.

Comment: @Uwe I haven't found a specific venting information for the ascent tanks. That being said, the LM RCS was hooked up to and could also be fed by the ascent engine tanks. At somewhere around 10x the normal amount of fuel it might take awhile, but they very likely could have fired off complementary RCS to draw down the tanks, especially given they had hours to do so. And again, this is before getting creative.